# Drupal 7: navigation menu with Views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I want to make a long page consisting of multiple nodes (each of the same Content Type). The page should have navigation on top of it that will allow to jump directly to the desired point of the long page, kind of like here: http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/features.html (there navigation is under the picture)

I used the Views module to assemble a long page from content, and for navigation I tried to use another View of the same content, only inserted in the top of the page as a block. I set this view to display grid of fields; it looks good. Only I could not figure out how to make each cell in the grid to become a link to the content on the same page.

I tried modifying views template, but there $rows variable turned out to be a string with already assembled html. Maybe I could possibly modify the content template, and insert some sort of condition that will change the way content looks based on what part of the page current view is located, but I am not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the views, edit the field selected, and there are options there to configure the field as hyperlinks how you may want them. Also you can just let the field link directly to the node, there is an option for that. cheers

Comment: Thanks, that worked. If someone else is looking for details that is what I did: 1.Add all fields that you want to appear. 2. Exclude each one from display. Add custom text field (it should be the very last one), and insert all the HTML markup that you want, using tokens from "replacement patterns" as your desired field values. Finally, check output the field as a link, and use token in the link too. This way the whole block will be clickable link, not just separate fields